# Setting Stroke on GradientDrawable Android

Tags: android, button, gradientdrawable

I am creating a custom Button and I am using the Drawable.setTintList to have colors for default,pressed and disabled states.
I want to actually add a border to the button, which I am trying by doing:

```
val d = newGradientDrawableForShape()
d.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE)

d.setColor(Color.WHITE)
d.setStroke(20, Color.GREEN)
```

With this the border is not visible, however if I do not use tint list then I do see the border.
Is there a way I can use setStroke and TintList?
I tried d.setStroke(width, colorList) and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

you can use drawable with state
example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#6699ff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#669900" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,
I am actually not using any xmls here since it is going to be part of a library, so need to do it programatically.
Plus I am already setting the background with the drawable object.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I also achieved another approach.

Here's the XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_card_header_large_border_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/view_card_header_large_border_base"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="?paper_color"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_card_header_large_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            ....
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the code:

```
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
            new int[] {leftColor, rightColor});

    // card background
    gradientDrawable.setAlpha(70);
    gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(borderBaseView.getRadius());
    container.setBackground(gradientDrawable);

    // card border's background, which depends on the margin that is applied to the borderBaseView
    gradientDrawable.setAlpha(90);
    gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(12dp);
    borderContainer.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
```

The idea is to set background to two views and the top view covers the "border" base view but leaves a `1dp` margin to be the "border".

So that you will have a gradient background in the view and also the gradient background in the border.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
setStroke(
     (strokeSize * resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt(), 
     ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context,colorRes)),
     0f,
     0f
)
```